# comparing dates in a table with tomorrow's date

Tags: php, sql, pdo

I am trying to comparte dates in a table with tomorrow's date.

I get the error: Syntax error or access violation: 1064 Erreur de syntaxe prés de 'DAY(start_datetime)=26'.

I have tried the following:

```
$year= date('Y',strtotime('tomorrow'));
$month= date('m',strtotime('tomorrow'));
$day= date('d',strtotime('tomorrow'));

$stmt4 = $pdo1->query("SELECT time_format(start_datetime,'%H:%i') from ea_appointments where 
YEAR(start_datetime)= ".$year." and MONTH(start_datetime)=".$month."and 
DAY(start_datetime)=".$day);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check your query first. There was a syntax error - lack of space after `AND` operator.

```
$stmt4 = $pdo1->query("SELECT time_format(start_datetime,'%H:%i') from ea_appointments where 
YEAR(start_datetime)=".$year." and MONTH(start_datetime)=".$month." and 
DAY(start_datetime)=".$day);
```

I also suggest using uppercase for the reserved keywords like SELECT and WHERE which increases readability. The same query may look like this:

```
$stmt4 = $pdo1->query("
SELECT TIME_FORMAT(start_datetime,'%H:%i')
  FROM ea_appointments
 WHERE YEAR(start_datetime)=".$year."
   AND MONTH(start_datetime)=".$month."
   AND DAY(start_datetime)=".$day
);
```

You can also rely on SQL date and time operations.
In the case of MySQL the query would look like this:

```
SELECT TIME_FORMAT(start_datetime,'%H:%i') 
  FROM ea_appointments 
 WHERE DATEDIFF(start_datetime, DATE_ADD(CURDATE(), INTERVAL 1 DAY)) = 0;
```